# Error CONCAT MySQL - No concat 2 or more values

Tags: mysql, sql, field, concatenation

Good day !

I try to execute the follow script:

```
SELECT 
concat_ws(", ",if(dep.id_departamento=0,"",ifnull(dep.descripcion,"")),
      if(mun.id_municipio=0,"",ifnull(mun.descripcion,"")) , 
      if(ifnull(vi.zona ,0)=0,"", cast(vi.zona as char))) as concatAddress
FROM visados vi
left join municipios mun on mun.id_municipio = vi.id_municipio
left join departamentos dep on dep.id_departamento = vi.id_departamento
```

The information on tables:

Visados - vi

```
+-------+--------------------+-----------------+---------+
|  id   |   id_departamento  |   id_municipio  |   zona  |
+-------+--------------------+-----------------+---------+
|   1   |        1           |        1        |    5    |
+-------+--------------------+-----------------+---------+
```

Municipios - mun

```
+------------------+---------------+
|   id_municipio   |  descripcion  |
+------------------+---------------+
|         1        | chimaltenango |
+------------------+---------------+
```

Departamentos - dep

```
+---------------------+---------------+
|    id_departamento  |  descripcion  |
+---------------------+---------------+
|           1         | chimaltenango |
+---------------------+---------------+
```

The correct result should be:

```
+------------------------------------+
|            concatAddress           |      
+------------------------------------+
|  chimaltenango, chimaltenango, 5   | 
+------------------------------------+
```

But my result is only:

```
+------------------+
|  concatAddress   |      
+------------------+
|  chimaltenango   | 
+------------------+
```

No Concat the other 2 value fields.

What happened ?

LocalServer: MySQL 5.6.25 Version

thank you !

Comment: I tried your query and get the correct result: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4d0ac3/1

Comment: So weird. I execute the same information in the link into my Local server and Production Server, and I got the same error.

Comment: Shouldn't `mun.id_departmento` be `dep.id_departmento`? You don't really need to put the aliases in the table diagrams, you have the table name above it.

Comment: Your query must be different from what you've shown. Because even if the join doesn't find matches, `IFNULL` prevents null values from being concatenated, so you should always get two commas, like `chimaltenango, , 5`.

Comment: I modify the aliases and query with some conditions.

Comment: It still works correctly: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4d0ac3/2.

Comment: I think my head will explode. Doesn't work on my Local and Production servers yet. Shows only 1 field. I don't know what more I need to do.

Comment: What MySQL version are you running?

Comment: Holy cow !! i'm feel like a donkey... because I don't verified this before. And we have  5.1 MySQL version. I'll update my local and production servers to verify if everything is ok. Probably will be right. Thank you master!

Comment: I update mysql on my Local to 5.6.25 and when I execute the query ocurred the same error. 1 field shows only again.

Comment: You must be doing a different query than what you showed. There's no way that can show just one field.

Comment: Belive me, I copy the query from sqlfiddle.com, I change the tables name and some words to spanish (I'm guatemalan), then I execute the query and show the same issue.

Comment: You need to post the actual query. You must be messing something up when you change those names.

Comment: Done. I modified to the original query and the original fields name.

Comment: I still can't reproduce it. See http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/521dfe/1 where I added additional rows with nulls and 0, they all resulted in comma-separated lists. Are you using another tool to display the result? Maybe it's removing things.

Comment: I tried to use Workbench and command line (mysqld). Matter the OS ? I use MacOS (I don't like this f** OS)

Comment: I tried it with the `mysql` command line on Linux, it works fine. I have Mac OS, but I don't have MySQL installed on it, but I wouldn't expect it to be any different. I'm at a total loss, sorry.

Comment: I Solved the problem ! each "descripcion" has "\r" at the end of text. Using "trim" I removed this return.

Comment: You should probably fix the code that inserts the descriptions so it doesn't do that.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that each row has a `\r` at the end of string.

Municipios - mun

```
+------------------+-----------------+
|   id_municipio   |    descripcion  |
+------------------+-----------------+
|         1        | chimaltenango\r |
+------------------+-----------------+
```

Departamentos - dep

```
+---------------------+-----------------+
|    id_departamento  |   descripcion   |
+---------------------+-----------------+
|           1         | chimaltenango\r |
+---------------------+-----------------+
```

Using [Trim](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-trim-function.php) I solved the problem:

```
SELECT
concat_ws(", ",if(dep.id_departamento=0,"",ifnull(trim(BOTH "\r" FROM dep.descripcion),"")),
      if(mun.id_municipio=0,"",ifnull(trim(BOTH "\r" FROM mun.descripcion),"")) , 
      if(ifnull(vi.zona ,0)=0,"", cast(vi.zona as char))) as concatAddress
FROM visados vi
left join municipios mun on mun.id_municipio = vi.id_municipio
left join departamentos dep on dep.id_departamento = mun.id_departamento
```

Thank you to all !